# Android: 360 degrees view of one object

Tags: android, object, view, 360-degrees

Is there any way to create a 360 degree object view from photos? I have a set of 71 photos of a single car viewed from different angles. I want to combine them and be able to rotate the car when touching the screen seeing it from different angles.
I've done researching but I couldn't find anything done in android. One example is found [here](http://blog.stableflow.com/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/)

This example is made with Jquery. What I need is to implement it directly inside an android app. How can I do this?

**Edit1:** Until now I managed to create an animation between images in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) way:

The problem is that the animation starts on click and works by itself. I want to be able to move the car from left to right and right to left when keeping the finger pressed and moving to right or left. How can I do that so I can see the car from the angle I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested that Jquery plugin page on my device and it seems to work alright. So you could still presumeably use that plugin to make some html content that you could then load into a WebView. That would give the rotation thing inside of your application.

If you don't want to use html/javascript to do it you'll have to use an ImageView with a TouchListener attached to it that handles the drag events by swapping to the next image at the appropriate interval.

Or probably somehow with Canvas, though I am not as familiar with that, I would knot how to describe what you'd need to do to make it work this way.

Comment: I found a way of doing it using Drawable animation as I described in Edit1 of my post. Do you have any idea how can make it move from left to right and backward as I touch the screen and move to the right or left?

Comment: @FoamyGuy Could you please help me out like how we can implement it Imageview and TouchListner ?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying to accomplish this task I stopped using the Drawable animation method because at point I was loading the images the app would of crashed because was out of memory.

Instead I found another way to do it which I use it right now. [Example](http://jbk404.site50.net/360DegreeView/mobile/common.html)

I changed the .html with the images I need and the layout I want then I implement it inside my app using a webview. Is working pretty well.